# Placing characters after an end statement - any benefit beyond readability?

Tags: coding-style, fortran

Beyond possible readability benefits, is there any reason to place a descriptor following an `end` in Fortran, e.g.:

```
subroutine foo()
    !> small code fragment
end subroutine foo
```

Versus:

```
subroutine foo()
    !> small code fragment
end subroutine
```

Obviously, for any code block that can't be viewed in a single instance, I can immediately see the value of such a closing statement, but, especially for small functions and type definitions it feels unnecessary verbose.

Not looking for a "opinion on whether its good style", or not, answer, but trying to understand further if there is something I am misunderstanding about the construction on such statements.

Comment: Use generic tag fortran to target wider audience. Besides, your question is applicable also to modern Fortran version, not just the very old Fortran 90.

Comment: My opinion: it really helps to identify which function ends here when scrolling through a file. It is annoying when you are copy pasting small procedures and forgetting to change the name at the end so I only use it for the longer ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a name is provided on an end statement, and that name does not match the name in the opening statement of the program unit or subprogram, then a conforming compiler is required to issue a diagnostic.  This may help locate coding errors.

Otherwise this is purely a question of style.